# Checked status not updated in CheckBox template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, checkbox, control-template

I'm trying to create an hyperlink that changes its text depending on a boolean value. I thought I could leverage the IsChecked method of a CheckBox. So I wrote this ControlTemplate for a CheckBox:

```
 <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeBool, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <CheckBox.Template>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
             <BulletDecorator>
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Hyperlink>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBoxHyperlink">Unchecked</TextBlock>
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <ContentPresenter />
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                       <Setter TargetName="TextBoxHyperlink" 
                               Property="Text" 
                               Value="Checked" />
                   </Trigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </CheckBox.Template>
    </CheckBox>
```

But when I click on the hyperlink, nothing happens. The checked status is not changed and the Text property of the TextBlock is not updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding text in the TextBlock element as content, you're setting a local value on the Text property.  Local values override values set by triggers, so your trigger will have no effect.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812822/textblock-text-property-cant-be-set-via-style-trigger-if-non-empty-why) or [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) on msdn.

If you set the Text property instead of adding it as content, it will be considered a parent template property set and be lower precedence than the parent template trigger:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBoxHyperlink" Text="Unchecked"/>
```

Also, it sounds like you're only using a CheckBox because you want a trigger based on a Boolean property.  You could use a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) instead of a Trigger to bind to a property on your DataContext instead of a property on your control, or you could just bind the Text property directly to SomeBool and use a value converter that converts true and false to "Checked" and "Unchecked".